# Test Class - System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I am getting an error `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

> Class.WebtoLeadScheduledProcess.sendMailDistribution: line 19, column 1
>   Class.WebtoLeadScheduledProcessTest.doTestWebtoLead: line 41, column 1

Can you please help me. I am unable to rectify this.

```
global class WebtoLeadScheduledProcess implements Schedulable
{

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){ 



  sendMailDistribution();
 } 

 public static void sendMailDistribution(){ 

   CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c mfauser = [Select Id, Name, CRS_W2L_Subject__c, CRS_W2L_CC_Email__c, CRS_W2L_FROM_Email__c from CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c limit 1];
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

  list<lead> webLead = [Select Name, Is_Web_Lead__c, WebToLead_User__c, Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c, RecordType.DeveloperName, leadsource,  status, Company, CRS_City__c, CRS_State_Province__C, CRS_Country__c, CRS_Zip__c, 
                          Phone, CRS_Application_Type__c, Comments__c, Email, FirstName, CreatedDate  from Lead where CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:9];
         Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> emd = new Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c>();
         List<CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> listCodes = CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c.getAll().values(); 
           OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'Test@example.com'];
              for(CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c c : listCodes){
            emd.put(c.State_Abbreviations__c, c);
           }

  for (Lead l : webLead ){
     if(l.Is_Web_Lead__c == True && l.status == 'open' && l.Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c == false && l.leadsource == 'Web Inquiry' && l.WebToLead_User__c == 'QUEUE' && l.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Carrier_Rentals_Lead') {
            CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c ems = emd.get(l.CRS_State_Province__C);
                  if(ems != null){
                   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                   mail.setSubject('Action required on Unclaimed Lead'); 
                  List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                  for(String key : ems.Email_Distribution_List__c.split(','))
                 {
                        sendTo.add(key);
                 }
                   mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                  mail.setReplyTo(mfauser.CRS_W2L_FROM_Email__c);
                  mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
                  String leadLink = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/' +l.Id;
                   String ecMsg = '<a style=\'color:1B2BE8\' target="_blank" href="'+leadLink+'">'+leadLink+'</a>';
                   String body = 'Hello <br><br>';
                     body += 'Test<br>';
                     body += 'Test.<br><br><br><br>';
                     body += 'Link to the Lead:    '+ecMsg+ '<br><br>';
                     body += 'Thank you. <br><br>';
                     mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                     mail.useSignature = false;
                     mails.add(mail);
             }
          }  
        }

       Messaging.sendEmail(mails);



      }
   }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest

private class WebtoLeadScheduledProcessTest
{

    static testMethod void doTestWebtoLead(){

     Test.startTest();

           lead l = new lead();
           l.Company = 'webtoleadTest';
           l.CRS_City__c = 'AK';
           l.CRS_State_Province__C = 'AK';
           l.CRS_Country__c = 'US'; 
           l.CRS_Zip__c = '7567890'; 
           l.Phone  = '835678936'; 
           l.CRS_Application_Type__c  = 'Test'; 
           l.Comments__c  = 'webtolead';  
           l.Email = 'test@example.com'; 
           l.FirstName  = 'Test';
           l.LastName  = 'Web'; 
           l.CRS_Address_Line_1__c = 'Test US';
           l.Industry = 'TestAK';
           l.Is_Web_Lead__c = True;
           l.status = 'open';
           l.Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c = false;
           l.leadsource = 'Web Inquiry';
           l.CreatedDate = system.today()-5;
           insert l;

      WebtoLeadScheduledProcess testsche = new WebtoLeadScheduledProcess();
       String sch = '0 10 23 * * ?';
       testsche.sendMailDistribution();
       system.schedule('Test status Check', sch, testsche ); 

       Test.stopTest();


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c mfauser = [Select Id, Name, CRS_W2L_Subject__c, CRS_W2L_CC_Email__c, CRS_W2L_FROM_Email__c from CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c limit 1];
```

will return zero rows and therefore result in that error. You need to insert at least one row into this object in your test before you invoke `sendMailDistribution`.

(That is not line 19 - I'm assuming you have neglected to post the exact code that the stack trace was reported with.)

**PS**

Your `Lead` query includes:

```
where CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:9
```

and a good way to set such a date in your test data is to use the recently introduced [Test.setCreatedDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCreatedDate):

```
insert l;
Test.setCreatedDate(l.Id, DateTime.now().addDays(-9);
```

By the way, rather than focussing on covering the code your focus should be on asserting that the code does the right thing. 100% coverage and the wrong results is not a good outcome. So add some asserts that confirm the expected results.

Comment: Thank you but still  if(l.Is_Web_Lead__c == True)&&.....Statement  onwards code coverage is not covering. Can you please help me.

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy I've added a PS that may help but the idea on this forum is to have one question and one answer not a sequence of fixes.

Comment: Yes but the main problem is I am unable to satisfy  if(l.Is_Web_Lead__c == True && l.status == 'open' && l.Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c == false && l.leadsource == 'Web Inquiry' && l.WebToLead_User__c == 'QUEUE' && l.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Carrier_Rentals_Lead') {... statement. UntilTest code is covering after that its not covering. I am trying from last 2 days. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy Your test will need to assign  `l.WebToLead_User__c = 'QUEUE';` and also query the ID of the 'Carrier_Rentals_Lead' record type and assign that to `l.RecordTypeId`.

Comment: l.WebToLead_User__c = 'QUEUE'; this field is Formula. unable to assign to the lead. The formula filed will check the UserID is QUEUE or USER. How to declare this Formula field in my test class,